# Adding an element to an associative array throws an error - php

Tags: php

I have an json-encoded array in my database which I like to add elements to. The json from the database looks like this:

```
{"1549006986":"a27f51b4dba8899c7a278465a873449a"}
```

Here is the code with which I want to add the element:

```
$tokenarray = json_decode($_SESSION['logintoken']);

$counttokens = count($tokenarray);

$newtoken = md5(mt_rand());

$datetime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

if ($counttokens < 6){

    $tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];

    }

$tokenarrayjson = json_encode($tokenarray);
```

But this line

```
$tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];
```

ends up in this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in **SITEURL** Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **SITEURL** on line
```

Can someone tell where im wrong here? From another post on this site, adding elements like this to an array should be valid from php version 5.4. I run on 7.2

Regards andreas

Comment: *"I have an json-encoded array in my database"* No. This is against the purpose of using a RDBMS

Comment: change `$tokenarray += [$datetime => $newtoken];` to `$tokenarray[$datetime] = $newtoken;`

Comment: @Cid - what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean do not store serialized datas in your DB. This is a pain to query (join, search, update, delete, ...)

Comment: I only need to query it for login purposes. To see if the cookie is valid, then never again. And I need multiple cookies to be valid because the consumer could login from more than one device. Is there a better solution to that?

Comment: _“From another post on this site, adding elements like this to an array should be valid”_ - only it doesn’t apply here, because you don’t have an _array_ - you have an _object_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your call to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Because you have not passed the second parameter as true, it is returning an object, which you are then attempting to use as an array, causing the errors you are seeing. If you had put a `print_r($tokenarray);` in your code after the `json_decode`, you would have seen this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [1549006986] => a27f51b4dba8899c7a278465a873449a
)
```

To fix it, change:

```
$tokenarray = json_decode($_SESSION['logintoken']);
```

to

```
$tokenarray = json_decode($_SESSION['logintoken'], true);
```

You also have a typo in your code,

```
newtoken = md5(mt_rand());
```

should be

```
$newtoken = md5(mt_rand());
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, it worked. Is a decoded json an object everytime in the first place?  And can you tell me the difference between an object and what I have here? :) Thank you

Comment: What makes the JSON decode as an object is that it is written as one, surrounded by `{` and `}` and with `"key" : "value"` pairs. What you need for your code is an associative array i.e. an array with non-numeric keys. Note that you could have used an object with a minor code change and you would get the same end result from `json_encode`, take a look at https://3v4l.org/fOipr

Comment: Aha, okay. - Can you tell me what would be better? Use it as an object or as an array? - And - This is an associative array.. only that I don´t have "keys", which I won´t need in that case, because I will throw out the token with the oldest timestamp. I don´t need to identify the tokens, I think :)

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer it's probably easier to use it as an array, as you can take advantage of all the array functions like sorting - to get rid of the oldest token, simply use `ksort` and `unset($tokenarray[array_keys($tokenarray)[0]]);`

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$tokenarray[$datetime] = $newtoken;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in **SITEURL** Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **SITEURL on line <- Now I get this error

Comment: Change `newtoken = md5(mt_rand());` to `$newtoken = md5(mt_rand());` notice `$` in starting

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have issue with your newtoken statement.

```
newtoken = md5(mt_rand());
```

You forgot to put $ before newtoken variable